# Latching circuit for ESP8266 with coin cell and Reed Switch

Tags: arduino, sensor, esp8266

I am trying to make a circuit referencing to a YouTube video to make my circuit last long on a battery cell (CR2032). I don't know where is the problem but here is the schematic diagram I created

https://easyeda.com/nehul.splendit/ESP-door-sen-mo[image]

**With this circuit the problem is. Its not turning ON the ESP-01s at all.**

I am not sure where I am wrong. As per my understanding I am making same as per the reference video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_A_8Y4xNx8

Any suggestions where is the problem in my circuit?

Here is how i have my code sketch:

```
int count = 0;
void setup() {
  pinMode(0, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {

  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
  count++;
  if(count == 5){
    delay(5000);
    digitalWrite(0, LOW);
    ESP.deepSleep(0);
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: This circuit is useless without supporting code. Something like described at the end of [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/394386/187920)

Comment: @Maple I just mentioned my code as well. Its a very simple blink program.

Comment: What is the measured voltage on VCC? Have you confirmed that your ESP circuit works with any other power supply?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson 3.3v I am using for testing on bread board.

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe you. Provide a link to the manufacturer's datasheet for a CR2032 that provides 3.3V. If you didn't measure it, it didn't happen. I suspect that your supply voltage is just too low, particularly when you try to light up an LED.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson same as you I had the same doubt that's why I created the same circuit on bread board where I am powering my circuit with NodeMCU 3.3v pin. To provide proper power supply. But unfortunately that is also not helping me to power my circuit.

Comment: Your schematics does not correspond to your code. There is no LED on schematics. The connection between GPIO2 and wakeup input is pointless when you configure it as an output. It can only make sense as an input to check outside signal before going to sleep, which is also unnecessary for correct functionality. Check the logic in the link I provided above, it is extremely simple.

Comment: @Maple GPIO2 is a builtin_led pin in ESP-01s. So i am not connecting any external LED here. Just using INBUILT LED pin.

Comment: Then why did you connect GPIO2 to wakeup input?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to pull down GPIO 0 to GND so that it has a known default state. This is the schematics that the video is based on:

[image]

Comment: Schematic posted here: https://imgur.com/tHOaPzJ

Comment: Yes i think you are correct  I need to try this.

Comment: If you see my schemetics is same as yours.

Comment: You can open easyEDA link. I have shared. And suggest the alterations if i am making any mistake here.

Comment: @perja What is the purpose of resistor to GPIO2? Copying schematics from somewhere on internet without understanding or explanation what you are trying to achieve is counterproductive

Comment: OK, good point. I was pointing to origin of the youtube video, but I see that it isn't very helpful.